# RequireJS text plugin empty in Cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, requirejs

I am trying to use the requireJS text plugin to load a text resource in a Cordova project:

```
var template = require( "text!app/assets/templates/stuff.html" );
```

However, I am only getting an empty string.  No errors anywhere I can see.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, figured it out.  For others who might encounter this problem...

XHR restrictions mean the text plugin can be wonky inside of Cordova.

The solution is to just require a javascript module that returns a text string.  So for example, stuff.html.js:

```
define(function(require) {

var tmpl = `
    <div>test</div>
    Ok here is a test
`;
return tmpl;

});
```

And then...

```
var template = require( "app/assets/templates/stuff.html" );
```

Shazam!
(And since back-ticks allow for multiline strings in ECMA6, it's still very readable.)